# Xcode debugger doesn't print objects and shows nil, when they aren't

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

Xcode shows an error when trying to print an object with `po <objectName>`, but only for one project.

[image: Screenshot]

> error: Couldn't materialize struct: size of variable <varName> disagrees with the ValueObject's size
>   Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression

The Xcode debugger also shows ALL objects as `nil` (`self` excluded), when they aren't (`NSLog` shows correct output, as seen in the image).
I don't know what's wrong with the project. Every other project works fine.

Any idea what it could be? (Cleaning the project had no effect.)

Comment: To me it sound like some kind of pointer issue, but i'm sure entirely sure to be honest. What are you trying to do/accomplish?

Comment: The error occurs on **every** object of that project. Even `NSString`s created one line above the breakpoint!

Comment: Maybe it's a system level error. Have you tried  cleaning it?

Comment: That's Product < clean  or shift,cmd, K

Comment: As said in the question, cleaning does not change anything ;(, but thanks for trying. Added the error message.

Comment: Are you sure that you are building without optimizations? (-O0)

Comment: Optimizations can be set not only in project settings but in targets also. There was m stuck :(

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Are you sure you are not in "Release mode"?

If you want to see variable values you have to be in "Debug mode" (click on your project name on the top left corner near start/stop buttons, then "Edit scheme...", then "Run" settings, then "Info" tab, then "Build Configuration". Here set "Debug". If it was on "Release" that's the matter you saw all nils).

Comment: I only have one configuration, how to change the configuration so that it is like a `debug configuration`?

Comment: Ah ok, I created an empty project and can now see all the differences in the `Build Settings`, the deployment property `Strip debug symbols during copy` was set to YES.

Comment: @Alex1987 I set `Strip debug symbols during copy` to `NO` and the `Optimization Level` to `None -O0` in the project `Build Settings`

Comment: Unfortunately, in certain situations lldb has been doing this when in debug mode, with optimizations off, and debugging symbols present.  Time to visit bug report.apple.com

Comment: @ctpenrose ditto. going into Debug mode / changing debug symbol stripping did nothing for me.

Comment: I have a custom configuration 'Debug_Staging' that is basically a copy of the original Debug and I'm also getting this error...

Comment: Had the same issue - Optimization level was "None". Problem was that Link-Time Optimization (LTO) was set to "Yes" also for debug mode.

Comment: It would just start doing it some times for no apparent reason, only restarting XCode helped me.

Comment: Just curious, do any of you have `Enable Address Sanitizer` on?

Answer (score 42):

I've set "Optimization Level" for Debug configuration to "None" and it solved problem.

- Go to project `Build settings`
- Search `Debug`
- Under `Apple Clang - Code Generation` check `Optimization Level`
- Set `Debug` to `None [-OO]`

After that, you will be able to see variable values in the debug area or console.
[image]

Comment: Funny, that didn't work. I did the opposite. I switched to `Fastest, Smallest[-Os]` and it worked.

Comment: Lots of different suggestions, but this one (setting Debug optimization to None) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 32):

Make sure that Address Sanitizer is turned off in your Scheme settings. The Address Sanitizer does not work well with the debugger.

1. Go to Edit Scheme (Product >> Scheme >> Edit Scheme), choose Run, and go to the Diagnostics tab.
2. Make sure "Enable Address Sanitizer" is off.

[image]

Comment: This was the solution for me. Apparently there are lots of reasons this can happen though.

Answer (score 16):

It seems everyone has their own solution.

For me, I use `Objective-C` and `Swift` at the same time.

First of all, go to `TARGETS -> Build Settings` and search the `code generation`

You’ll find `Apple LLVM 6.0`  and  `Swift Compiler`

Change their `Optimization Level` all to `None`, then Debug, you may find the value not `nil`

Amazingly once you can see the value, you solve this problem permanently,  then you can change the `Optimization Level` to it used to be.

Answer (score 11):

There are other ways this can occur. For me it was because the "Other C Flags" value was set to "-O2", even for the debug build. Turning this off for the debug build resolved the issue.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Filtered debug output]

For me, Xcode was filtering out the debugger output.  Make sure your output setting is Debugger Output or All Output

Answer (score 7):

I just encountered this issue and found that it was because `Deployment Postprocessing = YES` in the Build Settings.

Changing this to `NO` fixed it, as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

Xcode version: 6.0.1 (6A317) on OSX 10.9.5

Answer (score 5):

I just run into a similar problem: At one point suddenly the Xcode debugger printed out some object types especially NSStrings as (null) although they were initialized with a value. Printed out via

```
NSLog(@"String value: %@", myString);
```

the correct value for the object was shown.

Confusing! 
Solving the problem was rather easy: I just shut down Xcode and restarted my computer. After I restarted Xcode everything works fine again :).

Answer (score 5):

Make sure `Link-Time Optimization = No` for debug mode in Build Settings.

Comment: I just meet this issue in Xcode 8 only on my dynamic framework build settings ! Thx

Answer (score 3):

1. Delete Derived Data
2. Quite Xcode / Restart
3. Clean Project

That's all it took for me.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions here will also fix the bug where you see `error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier` every time you try to `po` a variable.

For me the solution was to go to `Build Settings` and search for `Optimization Level` and make sure each `Debug` setting was set to `None`.

Comment: This actually fixed it for me. Any idea what the downside is for disabling the setting?

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Other C Flags" in build setting and set debug value from -o2 to -O0

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this as well and when I found I was in release mode I switch to debug ... no fix. Turns out that I had to do a clean first (cmd+shift+k).

So I think what happens is that after built in release mode not everything is recompiled in develop and so lldb can't properly read the symbols. After cleaning and recompiling in develop it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran on this problem when some dependency was added in  a very specific way - it works but when you try to print something from this framework you get `error`

Solution  was to add this dependency in a general way

Answer (score -4):

The reality is that the system should work out of the box and doesn't due to links to a multiple quantity of different settings, to a point that things may work for you, or not.

Why doesn't the system allows always to debug when in debug mode is a mystery that only Apple can answer (if they cared, which latelly i doubt they do).

After all, the difference between debug / non-debug would be extra tables with metadata which only fill in memory / disk space.

If you are compiling against the simulator or a device directly, you will not care of those extra megabytes.

So we need to run extra loops to just do a very basic and plain thing that all ides that i know since last century do just fine.

And to add, for me what worked was changing on "Debug" the Link-Time Optimization from "Monolithic" to "No" (xcode 8).

Comment: Xcode = No package manager out of the box, autocomplete and other features work on will, compile times are huge, etc.