# Xcode debugger doesn't print object also not showing any error message

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am using Xcode 5.1.1, my debugger accept object when i try to print them but doesn't print details of it. Also it is not showing any error message.

I have checked all answer listed for one similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870176/xcode-5-debugger-doesnt-print-objects-and-shows-nil-when-they-arent) but didn't found any of such error in my xcode setting.

[image: Accepting object]

[image: After adding an exception breakpoint]

Can some one please tell me where else i need to check?

Comment: Try adding an exception breakpoint if you want more descriptive error messages.

Comment: adding an exception breakpoint doesn't give any error message it gives values in variable (see my edited question) but this is not best solution when i have array object of dictionaries in it..

Comment: You're not being very clear with what you want to accomplish. If you want logs of items, you can log using `NSLog`. You added a normal breakpoint, not an [exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode). When a breakpoint is triggered, mouse over the object like you are in the second screenshot. Then, click the tiny triangle to the left (of`@kunal`, in your case) to see more info on it.

Comment: well to be specific I need to know why xcode is not printing values of variable when I say po varible

Comment: I have added exception break point the way you mentioned in comment but still  xcode is not printing details of variable/object when I say po varible/object

Comment: I'm not sure about that, sorry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After checking all the buttons in debugger window, found there is button at bottom (default selected "All Output") which popup drop-down when we click on it.

This was set to 'Target Output' which causing the problem.  **Select option either 'All Output' or 'Debugger Output'**, then we can get values of variable/object when we say po variable/object.

[image: Solution]

Comment: Thanks! I switched to `Target Output` by accident and were thinking that nothing is printed because of some bugs.

Answer (score 5):

For me the issue was the filter. If you try to use `po variable` when the filter is on, the response may be filtered out and not show.

[image]