# Xcode 6 strange (null) object display in debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I'm seeing a strange behavior with Xcode 6 debugger.
I have created a singleton shared instance using the following code:

```
+ (instancetype)shared 
{
    static DataBaseManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[DataBaseManager alloc] init];
    });

   return sharedInstance;
}
```

Right after the object is initialized by calling the method like this:

```
DataBaseManager *manager = [DataBaseManager shared];
NSLog(@"");
```

I have placed a breakpoint on the "NSLog", and i'm seeing the following debugger status:

[image: Xcode 6 debugger screen capture]

I have made sure I'm launching on debug mode, and that the build settings are fine, following the question here: [Xcode debugger doesn't print objects and shows nil, when they aren't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870176/xcode-5-debugger-doesnt-print-objects-and-shows-nil-when-they-arent)

Any ideas on why this is happening? 
This is the first time i have ever seen this kind of strange behavior.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
**UPDATE**

A bug was reported to apple bug report system.
The bug status is: Duplicate of 17164538 (Closed) 

so it is probably a known bug in Xcode.
```

Comment: My experience with the Xcode debugger visualization is that it's pretty fragile. The thing you can rely on is the LLDB shell on the right. For example, `po manager`, `po manager->_databasePath`, … If you experience consistent issues you might want to file a bug report with Apple, though.

Comment: @DarkDust 'po manager' does prints the memory address of 'manager'. everything is working, but this issue is frustrating. thanks.

Comment: The Xcode variable display stuff is often worthless.  Any time you suspect it use `p` and `po`.  You'll save a lot of time.  (Also, of course, `NSLog(@"");` isn't going to show you anything.  And if that was supposed to be the *only* reference to `manager` then it's likely been tossed by the optimizer.)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be in `Release mode` while you are debugging your code.

If you want to see variable values you have to be in `Debug mode`. The steps are

1. Click on your project name on the top left corner near start/stop buttons
2. Go in `Edit scheme`
3. Go in `Run` settings
4. Go in `Info tab` and then `Build Configuration`
5. Set it to `Debug`

If it was on "Release" that's the matter you saw all nil. 
If still not working then try following in the project `Build Settings`

1. Set `Strip debug symbols during copy` to `NO`
2. `Optimization Level` to `None -O0`

Comment: Glad to know it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

> Try setting Deployment Postprocessing to NO inside your Build Settings and check.

Comment: made sure it's set to NO. just like stated in the question reference link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870176/xcode-5-debugger-doesnt-print-objects-and-shows-nil-when-they-arent

Comment: Sometimes this is not sufficient to avoid the "error: Couldn't materialize: couldn't get the value of variable VARIABLENAME: variable not available
Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `Link-Time Optimization` set to No for debug mode in Build Settings.

Comment: This worked for me! Xcode 8.1 beta debugging iOS 10.1 beta.