# Xcode debug inspector shows values as nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, null

I'm having a very weird problem - as you can see in the picture below, the debug shows that the program entered to the if statement, but the value of **color** is shown as *nil* !!!

obviously that's can't be true, and I suspect that the Xcode is showing incorrect values on the inspector \ variable view (at the debug area).

I have no idea - maybe my Xcode had too much vodka?

any HELP please???

***updates:***

- I tried to restart my mac - didn't help.
- my Xcode version: 6.4

[image: going in an if statement will nil argument]

Comment: What happens if you type `po color` in the debugger?

Comment: @rmaddy -  po color gives me:
error: warning: couldn't get cmd pointer (substituting NULL): extracting data from value failed
Couldn't materialize: couldn't get the value of variable color: variable not available
Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression

Comment: you can set the level of debug information in either your build configuration or maybe by target. Don't exactly remember how. Google it should not be to hard to find (if that is the problem).

Comment: @AviramNetanel Did you restart your xcode? Something it happens on my system and I just restart xcode or re-run the applicaiton. BTW what is your xcode version?

Comment: Did you check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/19870176/468724

Comment: Hi. I'm interesting wtf is XRC.sh? database? or what? Probably you need start a session before extract any value?
One more decision: you can create category of UIColor with necessary colors (set of methods which return colors) and use it instead of your approach.

Comment: XRC.sh gives you a dictionary with colors, basically color is assigned with UIColor.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with "Build Configurations", but with what the specific build configuration is running. You can copy / rename / change the build configurations at your will. However, just changing to the default configuration "Debug" doesn't solve the problem in xcode 8, and neither does changing the optimization levels, the other flags etc. Still waiting for a solution that works on all cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your scheme - **Run** tab on the left should have the *Debug executable* option checked.

If you are running on AdHoc \ Release mode, the debugger will not show the right values.

Change the "Build Configuration" to "Debug".

Answer (score 22):

I've seen the "extracting data from value failed" message (when doing a `po foo` at the LLDB prompt), even on debug builds . This appears to be an LLDB bug.

A workaround that worked for me was to cast the value to the expected return type (e.g. if it's an NSNumber, `po (NSNumber *)foo`).

Comment: Casting to `id` (e. g. `po (id)foo`) seems to work, too.