# Xcode debugger not printing variables in some files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an issue with the Xcode debugger. Everything works fine in general, I can print variables using `po <var>` normally... Except in some files, where I can't print anything, and I have a `error: Couldn't apply expression side effects : couldn't get the data for variable self`
 error in the console.

[image: Xcode debugger]

Weirdly, Xcode shows values correctly on the left debugger panel.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870176/xcode-debugger-doesnt-print-objects-and-shows-nil-when-they-arent

Comment: Xcode debugger is so buggy, use `debugPrint` in code instead, for printing.

Comment: @Lu_ I am actually in Debug configuration, Optimizations are set to Onone, I cleaned DerivedData... Everything seems to be OK :s

Answer (score 22):

Similar observations, all good on the left panel but printing ends with the same message. Quick *improvement* was to use:

```
po print(variable)
```

or

```
po debugPrint(variable)
```

Result - prints variable and appends the same error message.